# use host date in javascript counter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I am using this script for countdown in my site and it's work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 (function (e) {
e.fn.countdown = function (t, n) {
function i() {
    eventDate = Date.parse(r.date) / 1e3;
    currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3);
    if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
        n.call(this);
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
    seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
    days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
    hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds -= minutes * 60;
    days == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day") : thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day");
    hours == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours") : thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours");
    minutes == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("Minutes") : thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("Minutes");
    seconds == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("Seconds") : thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("Seconds");
    if (r["format"] == "on") {
        days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days;
        hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours;
        minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
        seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds
    }
    if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
        thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
        thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
        thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
        thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds)
    } else {
        alert("Invalid date. Example: 30 Tuesday 2013 15:50:00");
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}
thisEl = e(this);
var r = {
    date: null,
    format: null
};
t && e.extend(r, t);
i();
interval = setInterval(i, 1e3)
}
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
function e() {
    var e = new Date;
    e.setDate(e.getDate() + 60);
    dd = e.getDate();
    mm = e.getMonth() + 1;
    y = e.getFullYear();
    futureFormattedDate = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
    return futureFormattedDate
}
$("#countdown").countdown({
    date: "<?php echo $newcounter ?> ", // Change this to your desired date to countdown to
    format: "on"
});
     });

          </script>
```

but i have a problem. this script use my user computer date but i want use my site host date. how can change my date read from my host?
thank you.

Comment: If you want to use the server date and time, why don't you just include it in the page at the server? The example date: `"Example: 30 Tuesday 2013 15:50:00"` is likely not particularly useful, where is the month? ;-)

Comment: ouch... implied globals include `interval`. Do you honestly expect this code to work without a hitch?

Comment: how can use server date in my script?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this will work:

```
currentDate = <?php echo time() ?>;
```

Looks like `currentDate` is just a Unix timestamp which `time()` will provide for you.

Comment: Timestamps in `JS` are based on **milliseconds**, whereas in `PHP` they are based on **seconds**. So you have to append `'000'` string

Comment: Yes, but in the current JS code they convert the millisends to seconds before assigning it to `currentDate` so this code will work. That's what the `/ 1e3` does

Comment: thank you dear John i use this code currentDate = <?php echo time() ?>; but not work